# Does the new gmail API replace IMAP and POP?

Tags: gmail-api

There's a new [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/). Does this replace IMAP & POP? Are there cases where one is preferable to the other?

Comment: gmail api is only for gmail. IMAP and POP are standardized protocols, not owned by google. Unless a real standard emerges (quite hypothetical), IMAP and POP will subsists.

Answer (score 5):

The new API is designed for applications that integrate with gmail or need some mail functionality. CRM tools, workflow & automation, etc. For these use cases, the new API is a lighter weight way to access gmail without the complexity of IMAP.

Traditional mail clients like Outlook, Thunderbird, etc. should still use IMAP or POP.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail API does not support push notification, which is supported by IDLE in IMAP.

Comment: Gmail API _does_ support push notifications (now)!  :)  http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/05/gmail-api-push-notifications-dont-call.html